# Why is T_OBJECT_OPERATOR not an operator in PHP?

Tags: php

In the PHP manual, (at http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) 
`->` is called the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` token.

On the other hand, the PHP manual does not attribute any
operator precedence to it at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php,
the way it would for a normal operator.

Similarly, the PHP specification at https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/19-grammar.md
does not classify `->` as an operator but as a punctuator- which I find rather surprising.

Why is it so ?